# SHFileOpStruct do not rise a Supercopier

Tags: file, delphi, copy

I'm creatinga delphi app, using a cxShellListView. When i drag a file/folder from another cxShellLisView the app rise a Supercopier instance (i have it installed and active) and this is what i need.

In other part i use the SHFileOpStruct as follows:

```
function CopyFolder (aHandle : THandle; aSourceFolder, aDestinationFolder : string; aAction : Word; aMode : Integer) : Boolean;
const Aborted : Boolean = False;
var shfo : TSHFileOpStruct;
begin
  FillChar(shfo,SizeOf(shfo),$0);
  with shfo do
    begin
      if aAction > 2 then
        begin
          aAction := 2;
        end;
      if aMode > 5 then
        begin
          aMode := 1;
        end;
      case aAction of
        1: wFunc := FO_MOVE;
        2: wFunc := FO_COPY;
      end;
      pFrom := Pchar(aSourceFolder+#0+#0);
      pTo := Pchar(aDestinationFolder+#0+#0);
      case aMode of
        1: fFlags := FOF_SILENT;
        2: fFlags := FOF_ALLOWUNDO or FOF_FILESONLY;
        3: fFlags := FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION;
        4: fFlags := FOF_NOCONFIRMATION;
        5: fFlags := FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS;
      end;

      Result := (SHFileOperation(shfo)= 0) and (not Aborted);
    end;
end;
```

So, when I copy using this function, supercopier do not handle the copy, starting a standard Windows dialog instead.
Any suggestions of how to raise a copy that use any alternative copy method like Supercopier 4, or another installed in Windows.

Comment: What is supercopier?

Comment: Which windows version and 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: But my guess is that supercopier hooks `CopyFile` and friends, but not `SHFileOperation`.

Comment: Btw, you are triple null terminating the strings. Which is fine, but `PChar(aSourceFolder+#0)` is sufficient.

Comment: Supercopier is a Copy manager for windows, integrated with the shell:

Comment: I tried CopyFile, but do not work. I'll try IFileOperation interface, and lets see what happens. Thank you very much for your aswer... i'll post latter how IFileOperation interface goes...

Comment: Both windows, 32 and 64, MartynA

Comment: Oh, and tested in Windows 7 and 8.1

Comment: Done the experiment, with IFileOperation interface it does not work

Comment: Somebody Knows something about this particular?